# Google Tag Manager with ChaplinJS

Tags: google-tag-manager, chaplinjs

I am in the process of building a chaplinJS client app and needed capabilities to add google analytics.

I want to use Google Tag Manager (GTM) and added the tracking code to my html file. Then went on over to GTM and setup the PageView event tag.

For some reason none of the page view events after the initial load are trigged. Does GTM work with chaplinJS? I imagine its looking for url change and then pushes out a Universal analytics page view event.

Has anyone else done this? I suppose the other route could be to update application.coffee and listen for "route:match" event and then push out a pageview event. I figured its easier to do this with GTM because I can always add new tags as I go.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach listed here to get my pageView tracking working

http://decompile.it/blog/2013/06/21/integrating-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics-in-a-single-page-application/

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, throw virtual pageview event on every navigation and that should help getting all pages tracked.
I have used similar handling for my backbone single page application.